# Writing big-json stream to a file - why is it so slow?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a simple script that creates a large object and tries to save it in a file as a json. When I use `big-json` library it takes x4 more time than if I used just `JSON.stringify` - why is that ?

```
    import json from 'big-json'

    const myData = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
        myData.push({'id': i, 'name': 'SomeName'})
    }
    const fetchAt = new Date()
    const myDataFileWriteStream = fs.createWriteStream('./myfile.json')
    console.log("Starting saving ...")
    json.createStringifyStream({body: myData})
        .pipe(myDataFileWriteStream)
        .on('finish', function () {
            const writeAt = new Date();
            console.log(`Data written in ${(writeAt - fetchAt) / 1000} seconds.`);
        });

// this takes like x4 time than if I did just
//  fs.writeFileSync('./myfile.json', JSON.stringify(myData));
```

How can I improve its performance ?

Comment: Have you tried [asking the developer](https://github.com/DonutEspresso/big-json/issues)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I use big-json library it takes x4 more time than if I used just `JSON.stringify` - why is that?

Because it's a tradeoff you make by choosing `big-json`.

The `JSON.stringify()` API stringifies the (big) JSON object into memory, and you write it to a file from memory afterwards.

[`big-json`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-json) writes it to the stream as it goes, without needing to spend extra memory for the in-memory JSON representation. Also, `big-json` is written in JavaScript (well, [TypeScript](https://github.com/Faleij/json-stream-stringify/blob/master/src/JsonStreamStringify.ts)); the Node.js intrinsic `JSON` things are written in C(++), which is much faster than JavaScript.

> How can I improve its performance ?

I'm sure the underlying `json-stream-stringify` project is open to performance-improving pull requests.